# react-dropzone , isDragReject not working when file exceeds max size

Tags: reactjs, file, dropzone, react-dropzone

using react-dropzone,I added ,maxSize: 1048576, when i drag a file the exceed this size
isDragReject is false even that the file is rejected. how can i over come it ?

I tried to use onDragEnter and customize myself but i cant get the file that has been dragged in the onDragEnter function.